# How to Use buttons in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, button

I made an ArrayAdapter and Array list for a "merchandise" kinda view and now i want it so that everytime i I click the + button it increments the products quantity that I want/click on. I'm veeeery new to java and android Soz.

```
So I wanna add this

int quantity = 1;

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void displayQuantity(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText(number);
    }


    /** this method is used to increase quantity*/
    public void add (View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 1;

        Log.v("merch","Added +1");

        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }
```

to this:

```
public class merchandise extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        ArrayList<Merch> merchArrayList = new ArrayList<Merch>();
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT1"));
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT2"));
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT3"));
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT4"));

        merchAdapter merchAdapter =  new merchAdapter(this,merchArrayList);
        GridView merchListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.merch_grid_view);
        merchListView.setAdapter(merchAdapter);
    }
```

Things I tried: 
1) created a new class and just called it "merch_buttons", but i got an error saying "the method should be in the parent context to the view" and i don't understand that.
2) added it to the on create but realized you can't add a method to a method
3) added it AFTER the on create method but it gave an error saying that "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick".

4) Tried to make a very simple new class and an xml with one button and the text view but still got error at 3).... (also asked a question about that).

sooooooo, what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize every UI Widget after the setContentView in onCreate(); To give you an example how e.g.:

```
TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
```

If you want to access it globally,

```
public class merchandise extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);

        ArrayList<Merch> merchArrayList = new ArrayList<Merch>();
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT1"));
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT2"));
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT3"));
        merchArrayList.add(new Merch(R.drawable.icon,"PRODUCT4"));

        merchAdapter merchAdapter =  new merchAdapter(this,merchArrayList);
        GridView merchListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.merch_grid_view);
        merchListView.setAdapter(merchAdapter);
    }
```

These includes the button you are trying to use your onClick on.

Comment: Ok i've done that and then added the add method after onCreate as: `public void add (View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 1;

        Log.v("merch","Added +1");

        quantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
    }`. Now im getting a different error saying "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference"....Btw each new merch in the Array list has a button and i want it to add as increasing the number of the item wanted.

Comment: If you are generating TextView inside your class make sure to assign it's id as well. I think, the error is still in relation to your previous, all widgets e.g. TextView, Button, EditText etc, should be initialized w/ an ID and initialize with (findViewById) if you want to access them. An alternative is to use View Binding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kotlin

Comment: I have given the textview an id in the XML and am generating textViews within the ArrayList (so technically every new Merch I add has the textView of id quantity_text_view). when i press on any of the buttons they work on only the first Merch. So how do i make it that each button pressed corresponds to the textView of the merch it's in.

Comment: Is it possible if i can make it in a loop? and how

Comment: Ah, I can see what you try to do now, maybe you can try doing it with RecyclerView and a ViewHolder instead, try to find howtos, might not be available in PC for a while.